WSL/Docker "connection specific dns suffix"
I'm running a Debian docker image on windows.
The container is getting DNS from docker: 172.x.x.7
The docker DNS is working and using my local DNS: I can ping google.com or local services.
But docker on WSL is not inheriting my local DNS domain suffix, which is breaking scripts that work correctly when the docker image is mounted on the production server.
 eg (linux/docker) mount -t nfs myserver:/myshare /mnt/myshare
 eg (WSL2/docker) mount -t nfs myserver.mydomain:/myshare /mnt/myshare

Why is it so? And what (short of re-writing the scripts) can I do about it?
Windows: 10.0.19045.4651
WSL: 2.2.4
WSL distribution: docker-desktop-data
Docker Engine: 27.1.1
Debian: 12

Note: I see that the docker engine has a configuration file, config.json, and that "dns-search" is a documented option. This would allow me to configure a static domain name suffix, which is not exactly the same as using a DHCP-assigned connection-specific domain name suffix, (as happens when linux is a native host), but would be another option. HOWEVER, I, personally, have not been able to make it work. Docker Desktop overwrites the docker engine configuration file when it starts.

what (short of re-writing the scripts) can I do about it?
configure the test environment reflect the production environment.

Yes, that is the question: see OP. What can I do to configure this environment to match the production environment. That /is/ the whole point of docker images.

What can I do communicate.  The environments should be configured the same. If they are not, specify that and the difference. If they are, specify that. Also, that can't be "the whole point" of Docker. There are significant differences in Docker by platform and the supporting infrastructure. Another thing Docker absolutely cannot be is a substitute for knowing how basic technology such as name resolution works. This isn't a forum for questions that have so little information as to barely be language constructs.

You can remove any reference to "scripts" in the question. It should state: "in production, when an endpoint performs a query of a single label name, the endpoint where the query is run appends the DNS suffix. In the test environment, the endpoint executing the query does not append the DNS suffix. How can test be configured to append the DNS suffix to queries"?

I could remove the example, but your suggested edit substitutes a wall of text. In literature and film, they say "show, not tell", and I was taught the same in teacher training, I will substitute a better example (that does not include off-topic content as mine does), if you can come up with one.

Also, if you don't know what a "connection specific DNS suffix" is, then you aren't the target demographic for this question.

@user165568: it sounds like you are assuming it is resolved using a DNS suffix, which is the least efficient way of resolving the name.

I'm not making any assumptions, which is why I posted my actual use case. If you know a  solution to my use case, you may propose that as a solution instead of answering the question posed by the title.

@user165568: how are you validating on the endpoint that name suffix is used?

ahh, I see what you mean. Yes, I do not know of any other way of using my DNS server to resolve names other than providing a FQDN to it. I'm not using the endpoint primary suffix, the DNS replies with the connection-specific FQDN, since it is incapable of self generating that request, the endpoint must have generated it. But I have not done packet capture.
